# Inserting node in YAML does not shift comments

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have to update a YAML file with new entries. I am inserting data at a particular index and it is failing for one case: when there is a comment present after the index at which the entry is to be added.

Code:

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML
import sys

stream = """
# Starting comment
test : 123
# Comment before test3
test3 : 12.23.532.2
"""

yaml = YAML(typ='rt')
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
yaml.default_flow_style = False
dic = yaml.load(stream)
dic.insert(1,"test-demo","value-demo")
yaml.dump(dic, sys.stdout)
```

I am getting below output:

```
# Starting comment
test: 123
# Comment before test3
test-demo: value-demo
test3: 12.23.532.2
```

Expected output is:

```
# Starting comment
test: 123
test-demo: value-demo
# Comment before test3
test3: 12.23.532.2
```

Ruamel.yaml version :

```
ruamel.yaml==0.17.10
ruamel.yaml.clib==0.2.6
```

How to avoid this and add the data correctly to the YAML?

Comment: I don't know where your faulty expectation comes from. End-ofl-line comments and everything following (empty lines, full-line comments) up until the next key are assocated with the preceding key (or in case of a sequence, the preceding element). This is a parsing issue, the next key has not parsed yet when the comment token must be attached to a node. `# Comment before test3` should read: `# Comment after test`

Comment: @Anthon. Thanks for the clarification. But if I want to add value in above case and get the expected result, what is the right course of action?

Comment: If you are inserting a key at a specific posiition you should inspect the comment on the key before it, split it it (because you should at least let that key keep its EOL comment) and than assign the comment to the key added. Look at the working code in the answer to the linked question in the "this question has an answer here"